# C# gmail notifer code. make it repeat?

Tags: c#, loops, notifications, gmail

this code checks if i have mail from gmail, then sends m over serial to a arduino if their is mail.

Ok so my code wont compile (error saying object reference required on code"CheckMail();") unless i change Main to non static like it is now , then it wont compile because theirs no static Main, im stumped.

also, how do i make this repeat so that it checks for messages every minute?

Thanks!!!

EDIT\\
OK YES!!! i got a working com emualtor finally. after your guys help it works but it only refershes twice (instantly not 60sec apart). the CMD stays open, it just stops after saying Unread Mail:2 Unread Mail:2 then i get operation timed out, Unread Mail:0 even though i have unread mails. even if i change { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000 * 60); } to a longer time it still has same time between refreshing the first two times.

(the namespace, class and using Sytem etc arent in here.)

```
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort( "COM9", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One );
            port.Open();

            string Unreadz = "0";
            while ( true ) {
                Unreadz = CheckMail();
                Console.WriteLine( "Unread Mails: " + Unreadz );

                if ( !Unreadz.Equals( "0" ) ) port.Write( "m" );
                else port.Write( "n" );

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch ( Exception ee ) { Console.WriteLine( ee.Message ); }
    }


    public static string TextToBase64(string sAscii)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(sAscii);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    private string CheckMail() {
        string result = "0";

        try {
            var url = @"https://gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom";
            var USER = "username";
            var PASS = "password";

            var encoded = TextToBase64( USER + ":" + PASS );

            var myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create( url );
            myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            myWebRequest.Headers.Add( "Authorization", "Basic " + encoded );

            var response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( stream );
            while ( reader.Read() )
                if ( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element )
                    if ( reader.Name == "fullcount" ) {
                        result = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        return result;
                    }
        } catch ( Exception ee ) { Console.WriteLine( ee.Message ); }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ( true ) {
  try {
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort( "COM9", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One );
    port.Open();

    string Unreadz = "0";

      Unreadz = CheckMail();
      Console.WriteLine( "Unread Mails: " + Unreadz );
      if ( !Unreadz.Equals( "0" ) ) port.Write( "m" );
      else port.Write( "n" );

  } catch ( Exception ee ) { Console.WriteLine( ee.Message ); 
  } finally { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*60); }
}
```

EDITED: With working loop.

Should work for it to check every 60 second.

And CheckMail ain't `static` (that's why it wont compile)

Comment: As per the code, the while loop wont sleep for 60 secs 1s it finishes its job of checking before it checks again right, coz your sleeping main thread in the finally block.

Comment: Works!!!. what i did: so i added that code over the old stuff then changed get mail to staic also!

Comment: Is the question answered then?

Comment: yes i believe so but ill wait until i get my comport up and going to confirm :) do you guys recommend any com port emulators?

Comment: OK YES!!! i got a working com emualtor finally. it works but it only refershes twice. the CMD stays open, it just stops after saying Unread Mail:2 Unread Mail:2 tehn i get operation timed out, Unread Mail:0 even though i have unread mails. even if i change { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000 * 60); } to a longer time it still has same time between refreshing the first two times.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to move the `while`-loop outside of the `Sleep` call.

Comment: i got it to work by adding the finally like to the end of private string CheckMail() { is your way better/ more efficient?

Comment: alright Thanks!! i would have a solution up but i dont have enough Rep. i dont know if this is aloowed but if anyone wants to help me on my other C# proram for my arduino http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138922/shared-memory-c-pc-stats-aida64

Comment: You could mark the answer as an answer (green tick below the points)

Comment: ok did that, wow you seem like the only nice person ive met so far. the rest seem like grump 40yr olds. Thanks. EDIT did you tell me to do that so you could get more rep :D

Answer (score 3):

Make CheckMail static as well.

Comment: Thanks! added the code below and made checkmail as static :) Now ill emulate a com port and see what i get.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry mate, your forgetting the basics of the language here. Plus you can have a timer on the main thread and call mail check operation every time on timer elapsed based on the timer count you set. Make sure you lock the mail check method for thread synchronization or else youll run into problems. Or make sure your checkmail operation completes before timer elapses.

Answer (score 0):

ok to fix the problem, i added this code in replacement of the old stuff:

```
try {
  SerialPort port = new SerialPort( "COM9", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One );
  port.Open();

  string Unreadz = "0";
  while ( true ) {
    Unreadz = CheckMail();
    Console.WriteLine( "Unread Mails: " + Unreadz );
    if ( !Unreadz.Equals( "0" ) ) port.Write( "m" );
    else port.Write( "n" );
  }
} catch ( Exception ee ) { Console.WriteLine( ee.Message ); 
} finally { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*60); }
```

then i added: "finally { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*60); }"
to:

```
private string CheckMail() {
        string result = "0";

        try {
            var url = @"https://gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom";
            var USER = "username";
            var PASS = "password";

            var encoded = TextToBase64( USER + ":" + PASS );

            var myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create( url );
            myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            myWebRequest.Headers.Add( "Authorization", "Basic " + encoded );

            var response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( stream );
            while ( reader.Read() )
                if ( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element )
                    if ( reader.Name == "fullcount" ) {
                        result = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        return result;
                    }
        } catch ( Exception ee ) { Console.WriteLine( ee.Message ); }
        return result;
    }
```

and to fix the static issue i made " private string CheckMail() {" "private static string CheckMail() {"

Thanks for all the help!!!